# How to implement validations in multi language support website?

Tags: reactjs, validation, multilingual, react-i18next

I am currently implementing the multi language support in one of the website which is being implemented in react as front end tool. I am using react-i18next library for the translation of UI literals in the site. But I am not getting how to implement the various validations in the site , because the regex which I shall use in one text area for english language, shall not work with other language (e.g: Japanese). Kindly help me to figure out this.

Comment: You're correct - using a regex wouldn't be practical for different languages/different character sets.  But you don't *NEED* to use a regex to validate a field

Answer (score 0):

What kind of validation are we talking about? Could you give some examples?

For most values the language shouldn't matter e.g numbers are all the same. Select options don't depend on the language - use the default language (before translating) to do the validation and only then translate.

For example:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(i18.t("This field is required")),
  pin_number: yup.matches(/\d{4}/, t("Is not in correct format"))
});
```

However if there is validation that is specific to a language, then yes you need to create a separate regex for each of them.

```
getLanguageSpecificRegex = () => {
  let regex;
  if (i18n.language === "en") {
    regex = "C\d+";
  } else (i18n.language === "et") {
    regex = "K\d+";
  } else {
    regex = "\d+";
  }
  return regex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as Regex, there is also date format and number format to consider, but regex is the biggest problem. Step 1 has got to be

**i18n your regexes as well as your validation strings**

so that you validation against e.g.

```
new Regex(i18n.t('regexFirstName'))
```

Instead of against `/\w+/`

Markup becomes messier if you are using a declarative markup validation framework:

```
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <input name="firstName" regex={new Regex(i18n.t('regexFirstName'))}  />
        ...
    )
```

but if you are setting validation in code then using

```
new Regex(i18n.t('regexFirstName'))
```

instead of

```
/regexLiteral/
```

is not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [strategy design pattern](https://dev.to/carlillo/design-patterns---strategy-pattern-in-javascript-2hg3).

You need to implement different strategies for different languages for your validation.